# Loading json data into angularjs ng-repeat and outside of ng-repeat from same json file

Tags: angularjs

i'm new to angular and a little lost. i'm able to load the data and display it, but i'm confused about loading other data that is not part of the ng-repeat i have set up from the same json file. here is what i have so far.

i would like to not use $scope.titleName = "John Doe";          $scope.infotext = "some more info" and have this info come from within the json file.

thanks for any help you can give.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);



 app.controller('something', function ($scope, $http){
  $http.get('site.json').success(function(data) {
     $scope.sites = data;
     $scope.titleName = "John Doe";
     $scope.infotext = "some more info"
  });
 });



/* json file content */

[
  {
    "name": "tim",
    "image": "/features/home-1.jpg",
    "link": "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
  },
  {
    "name": "don",
    "image": "/features/home-1.jpg",
    "link": "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "image": "/features/home-1.jpg",
    "link": "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
  },
  {
    "sub": {"titleName": "Homer", "infotext":"two"}
  }
]
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="something" >
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>{{titleName}}</h1>
            <p class="info">{{infotext}}</p>
            <div class="big"  ng-repeat="site in sites ">
                <a href="{{site.link}}" target="_blank">
                    <img src="{{site.image}}">
                </a>          
                <h2>{{site.name}}</h2>

            </div>
        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: What is your exact problem. I couldn't understand it. Can you provide more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Change your JSON because the last object of the array is different from sites, I suggest to have a JSON like this :

```
{
    "sites": [{
        "name": "tim",
        "image": "/features/home-1.jpg",
        "link": "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
    }, {
        "name": "don",
        "image": "/features/home-1.jpg",
        "link": "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
    }, {
        "name": "Mike",
        "image": "/features/home-1.jpg",
        "link": "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
    }],
    "sub": {
        "titleName": "Homer",
        "infotext": "two"
    }
}
```

You have also to modify your controller

```
app.controller('something', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('site.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.sites = data.sites;
        $scope.titleName = data.sub.titleName;
        $scope.infotext = data.sub.infotext;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but now my data is not loading for sites. do i need to make a change to the controller to make it work?

Comment: Change $scope.sites = data; to $scope.sites = data.sites;

Comment: my ng-repeat="site in sites " is still not loading, but $scope.titleName = data.sub.titleName;  $scope.infotext = data.sub.infotext; are laoding fine. do i need to change ng-repeat?

Comment: you should have seen that I made a little error and uses `data.site` instead of `data.sites`